# SwitchMaterial, TextOn and TextOff do not work

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

This is my simple view where I want to show this switch with two types of text, one text when it is selected and one when it is not:

```
   <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                android:id="@+id/switch_editable_by_client"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/base_margin"
                android:textOff="@string/switch_text_off"
                android:textOn="@string/switch_text_on"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editable_by_client_section" />
```

It would appear that this text is not shown in fact here is a preview from android studio:
[image: Deprecated?]

Does anyone have any solutions or dark magic?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the two parameters textOn and textOff refer to the text that can be inserted on Thumb of the switch which is settable directly from the view but the `app:showText` parameter must be set to true in the following way:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                android:id="@+id/switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="Off"
                android:textOn="On"
                app:showText="true" />
```

Obtaining:
[image: Non è quello che mi serve]

Being novice and not having read the documentation I had assumed that textOn and textOff would cause text to appear NEXT to the switch, as would happen if I set text exclusively in the following way:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                android:id="@+id/switch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="lorem ipsum" />
```

Here is the result:[image: What I would have wanted but with the behavior of textOn and textOff]